# PHP error not show in mamp

Tags: php, apache, mamp, mamp-pro

Im trying to display php error in mamp, but unfortunately error is not shown.

I've follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297618/mamp-config-help-display-php-errors) instruction, but it does't work.

and i can't change Loaded Configuration File [image]
[image]

anybody can help me to how to enable display_error?

Answer (score 0):

After editing the php.ini resart the server it should work